# Cross Correlations Reversed - SPSS and R

Tags: r, spss, cross-correlation

I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed that cross-correlations are reversed between SPSS and R.   Here is an example of the exact same data run in both R and SPSS (V23).  Note how the the axis is reversed.  So, which one is right?  In the R version, one might interpret it as X leading Y, while SPSS one might interpret it as X lagging Y.

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253778/interpreting-output-from-cross-correlation-function-in-r) also might help answer, but I'm not sure sure it actually applies.

any insight/experience appreciated.

[image: R Cross Correlation Output (>>ccf(x,y))]
[image]

Comment: Look at your data. Are the data the same? Or was there an error when moving between R and SPSS?

Comment: it is exactly the same data.  both variables have been differenced, so like this: ccf(diff(x), diff(y)).  same in SPSS.   If anyone has access to both R and SPSS, and would like to try, here is a link to Google Drive with the sample data:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Iy2LqHsDbkPbV1zb7jBkE-1jl4Z40NDA

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I may have answered my own question.

SPSS writes:

"The basic specification is two or more series names. By default, CCF automatically displays the cross-correlation coefficient and standard error for the negative lags (**second series leading**), the positive lags (**first series leading**), and the 0 lag for all possible pair combinations in the series list. It also plots the cross-correlations and marks the bounds of two standard errors on the plot. By default, CCF displays and plots values up to 7 lags (lags −7 to +7), or the range specified on TSET."

which I re-wrote to work with my brain:

By default, CCF automatically displays the cross-correlation coefficient and standard error for:

1. the negative lags (y leading x)
2. the positive lags (x leading y)
3. and the 0 lag for all possible pair combinations in the series list

It also plots the cross-correlations and marks the bounds of two standard errors on the plot. By default, CCF displays and plots values up to 7 lags (lags −7 to +7), or the range specified on TSET.

there is also a good reference [here](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/74/), which seems to support this assertion, and indicates that R is correctly displaying the x lags on the negative (left) side of the ccf output.